# Java Calculation Error

Tags: java

I've been writing a program for my uni course and I'm stumped on something that is probably ridiculous.

Here's a bit of my code

```
// International Calls Selection

            System.out.println("Would you like to include international calls?");
            System.out.println("1. Include");
            System.out.println("2. Do not Include");
            int intCallChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
            boolean intChoice = true;

            if (intCallChoice == 2)
            {
                intChoice = false;
            }
```

This part takes the input from the user as you can see, then in my contract class I have a price calculator method which goes like this:

```
    if (intChoice = true)
    {
        priceOfContract *= 1.15;
    }
```

However, the result always ends up being a 15% increase, no matter if I select to include International Calls or to not include them?

Comment: In the code `if (intChoice = true)` you are assigning value to `intChoice` instead of comparing it. To compare, replace the code with `if (intChoice == true)` or simply `if (intChoice)` as it is boolean variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (intChoice = true)
```

will always be true because you are using assignment(single =) and not equals(double ==)

Your condition should be

```
if (intChoice == true)
```

or simply

```
   if (intChoice) // for boolean check
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `==` instead of `=` like this:

```
 if (intChoice == true){
```

The `=` it is used for assign, but `==` it's used to check equality.
Or use just:

```
  if (intChoice){
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you need to use `==` to compare values, however since your variable is a boolean you can shorten this if statement even further:

```
if (intChoice) {
    priceOfContract *= 1.15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (intChoice = true)
```

Is a condition, and when you want to compare the intChoice variable value with true, you must use two equal signs (==), the same way you did in:

```
if (intCallChoice == 2)
```

If you use only one equal sign you are changing the value of the intChoice variable to true and the condition will be allways

```
if(true)
```

Which means for any type of calls the priceOfContract will be multiplied by 1.15.